# trying to display pdf in view in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I'm trying to do is display a pdf inline in my RoR app. I created a new folder in my assets folder called portfolio and put a pdf file in there. Here is what I'm doing in my controller:

```
                def portfoliopdf

              send_file(Rails.root.join("assets", "portfolio", "Portfolio.pdf").to_s, :disposition => "inline", :type => "application/pdf")
              end
```

For whatever reason I keep getting the following error -  ActionController::MissingFile in PagesController#portfoliopdf

Cannot read file C:/Sites/inspired/assets/portfolio/Portfolio.pdf

Also I created portfolio.html.erb and have it blank. I also added this in application.rb (not sure if this needs to be tweaked)...

```
                config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "portfolio")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After compiling the assets, your pdf is stored here

```
{Rails.root}/public/assets/Portfolio.pdf
```

and it's web path is

```
/assets/Portfolio.pdf
```

Therefore you may need to use

```
Rails.root.join("public", "assets", "Portfolio.pdf")
```