# open a pdf file in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I've uploaded a file, Resume.pdf, to the "images" folder in my "assets" folder. How can I create a link that will allow my users to open it?

In my WelcomeController, I have

```
 def readpdf
    send_file(Rails.root.join("public", "assets", "Resume.pdf").to_s, :disposition => "inline", :type => "application/pdf")
 end
```

My link is:

```
<li><%= link_to "RESUME", {:controller=>"welcome", :action=>'readpdf'}, :target=>'_blank' %> %></li>
```

I keep getting the error

```
ActionController::MissingFile in WelcomeController#readpdf 
Cannot read file /home/action/workspace/wolframpant/public/assets/images/Resume.pdf
```

I know similar questions have been asked (particularly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391208/trying-to-display-pdf-in-view-in-ruby-on-rails-app)), but as far as I can tell I'm doing everything the answers to those questions suggested.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: put your resume.pdf in your assets/images folder.

Comment: Put your `Resume.pdf` to `public` and use `/Resume.pdf` URL.

Comment: martin, that's where it is (as I said in my question). maxd, that worked!

Answer (score 2):

To access the asset it self you can use

```
<%= asset_path 'Resume.pdf' %>
```

To turn it to a link then couple it with a `link_to`

```
<% link_to 'Download the resume', asset_path 'Resume.pdf' %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I put that in a page I just get /assets/Resume.pdf printed on the page. Any other ideas?

Comment: that's the point, you take it and create your link using link_to, I'll update the answer